# How to give it check the div id feature?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently I've got into a problem. I want to add this code at my blogger templete. I've gave it replace 'display:none; css' option, replace the credit URL with my homepage features. But the `if (footer === null) {window.location = 'http://google.com';}` isn't working. why? Is anything wrong? I want to make client blog redirect if they remove the `id='mycreditlink'` attribute. I want to do this without jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function creditprotection(){

                var url = ('http://grplusbd.net');
                var style = ('display: inline; visibility: true;');
                var footer = document.getElementById('mycreditlink');

                footer.href= url;
                footer.style = style;

                if (footer === null) {
                window.location = 'http://google.com';
                }
            }

             window.onload = function(){creditprotection();};

        </script>   



    </head>


    <body>

            Powered By <a href='http://google.com' id='mycreditlink'> My Site </a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's impossible to ever get there. If `footer === null` is true, then the code has already crashed because it can't set `href` or `style` on a null reference.

Comment: thanks for your help, now it is working... i've placed the footer.href= url; and  footer.style = style; in the else{} after the if(footer === null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function creditprotection(){

            var url = ('http://grplusbd.net');

            var style = ('display: inline; visibility: true;');

            var footer = document.getElementById('mycreditlink');

            if (footer == null) {

                 footer.href= url;

                 footer.style = style;

                 window.location = 'http://google.com';
            }
        }window.onload = function(){creditprotection();};

    </script>
</head>

<body>

Powered By <a href='http://google.com' id='mycreditlink'> My Site</a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function like this:

```
function creditprotection() {
  var url = 'http://grplusbd.net';
  var style = 'display: inline; visibility: true;';
  var footer = document.getElementById('mycreditlink');

  if (footer === null) {
    window.location = 'https://google.com';
  }

  footer.href = url;
  footer.style = style;
}
```

When `footer` is not set, it does not have the properties `href` or `style`. That's when you get an error. This can be prevented by checking when `footer === null` before you assign the values to the footerproperties. If the `footer === null`, it redirects. Else it assigns the values.